# Inhabilitar fechas mayores a la actual en un input date

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario el cual posee un `input type="date"`  Me gustaría que las fechas posteriores a la fecha actual estén inhabilitadas ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Hola,puede tratar de mejorar tu pregunta mirando este link [ask], trata de mostrar lo que llevas o que haz intentado, para que te puedan ayudar . Saludos.

Comment: podrias usar algo asi: <input type="date" name="fecha" max="1979-12-31">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el atributo max="xxxx-xx-xx" en la etiqueta input. Si es php puede usar

```
max="<?php echo date(Y-m-d)?>"
```

Con javascript puedes usar (Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378590/set-date-input-fields-max-date-to-today):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Con php me lanzo un error de advertencia, pero con javascript me funcionó justo como quería. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo agregando el atributo `max` o `min`, te dejo el ejemplo:

```
<input name="somedate" type="date" min="2018-07-19">
```

Pero si deseas que sea tomando de base el día actual puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("somedate")[0].setAttribute('max', today);
```

```html
<input name="somedate" type="date">
```

Sería cuestión de cambiar el `max` por `min` o viceversa dependiendo de si quieres que el día de hoy sea fecha mínima o máxima.

Espero sea de tu ayuda.
Saludos.