# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un id como parametro de una función?

Tags: javascript, html

Hace una semana realicé la pregunta sobre cómo podía [inhabilitar fechas mayores a la fecha actual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182562/inhabilitar-fechas-mayores-a-la-actual-en-un-input-date) en un `<input type="date">` y me sugieron el siguiente código, el cual me funcionó:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);
```

Decidí colocarlo en un archivo .js externo dentro de una función llamada "validarFecha()", así no tendría que escribir todo el código debajo de cada `input` . Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que tengo diferentes `<input type="date">` con distintos id. Y me gustaría pasar la `id` como parámetro para que me funcione en todos los `<input type="date">`, de modo que solo tenga que llamar a la función, pasandole como parámetro la id del `input`

Intente cambiar `document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);` por `document.getElementsByClassName("datefield").setAttribute("max", today);` colocándole a cada input un `class="fecha"` pero no me funcionó. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es asignando una clase a los inputs en los que quieras hacer la validación

```
<input type="date" class="fecha">
```

Luego en el el script, debes seleccionarlos por clase.

```
function validarFecha() {
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if (dd < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd
            }
            if (mm < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm
            }
            today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;            
            var list = document.getElementsByClassName("fecha");
            for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
                list[index].setAttribute("max", today);
            }                        
        }
```

Y finalmente llamas a la fucnion validarFecha() dese el html en Body onload

```
<body onload="validarFecha()">
```

Comment: Gracias @Hugo , resolvió el problema y me ayudó a entender que no es necesario llamar a la función debajo de cada elemento donde la necesite. Aún me falta mucho por aprender...

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas pasar el id del elemento. Lo más práctico sería que agrupes esos elementos (por ejemplo por una clase), que encuentres en Javascript los elementos con esa clase y les asignes un listener que sería tu función.

Observa el siguiente ejemplo: hay varios inputs, y a los que me interesa yo les asigno `class="fecha"`, luego selecciono todos esos elementos y les asigno la función `readDate`. La ventaja haciendo eso es que:

- puedo asignar cualquier escuchador de eventos a todos mis elementos agrupados (en el ejemplo les he asignado un listener para cuando cambie alguno de esos elementos, pero le puedes asignar cualquier otro, o varios...)
- dentro de la función puedo obtener cualquier propiedad del elemento mediante `this` ( en el ejemplo obtenemos el id y el value del elemento).

```js
/*Asegurarse de que el DOM está cargado*/
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  /*
    Seleccionamos todos los elementos con la clase fecha
    la selección se puede refinar si se quiere
    por ejemplo, indicar solamente los elementos input con esa clase
  */
  var elFecha = document.querySelectorAll(".fecha");

  /*
     elFecha tendrá todos los elementos con la clase
     los recorremos y aplicamos un listener que será la función readDate
  */

  elFecha.forEach(function(el, idx) {
    el.addEventListener("change", readDate, false)
  });

});

/*
    Podremos usar  this+propiedad  
    para obtener lo que deseemos del elemento
    aquí obtenemos por ejemplo el id y el value
*/
function readDate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var txtTest = `Has pulsado el elemento con id: ${this.id}\nSu valor es: ${this.value}`;
  alert(txtTest);
}
```

```html
<input name="ibxNombre" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Nombre" />
<br />
<input name="ibxApellido" type="text" placeholder="Escriba Apellido" />
<br />


<input name="ibxNacimiento" id="ibxNacimiento" class="fecha" type="date" placeholder="Escriba fecha de nacimiento" />
<br />
<input name="ibxIngreso" id="ibxIngreso" class="fecha" type="date" placeholder="Escriba fecha de ingreso" />
```

Comment: La verdad se me hizo difícil entender el código, dado que llevo muy poco tiempo aprendiendo javascript. La función me marcaba la fecha actual, pero no inhabilita las fechas posteriores, tal vez no supe utilizarla. Igual muchas gracias por comentar @A.Cedano